# phyton/pandas: Отбор данных из таблицы по двум значениям из одного столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста, вытащить данные из столбца по 2-м признакам.

В общем, у нас есть датафрейм, с данными по продажам игр:

[image: датафрейм - df]

Сперва я отбираю игры по определенным платформам в сводную таблицу act_platforms, всё получается:

[image: датафрейм - act_platforms]

теперь, из полученного датафрейма мне нужно взять данные только по 2015-му и 2016-му году, в связи с чем я пробую разные варианты кода:

x = act_platforms [act_platforms['year_of_release'].isin (['2016', '2016'])]
или
x = act_platforms.query('year_of_release == "2015" and year_of_release == "2016"')

но, что бы я не пробовал, формируется только пустая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и меня это доводит до белого каления, потому что я ума не приложу что не так! Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с проблемой!

Comment: а какой тип данных вашей колонки "year of release"? `act_platforms.info()` покажите.

Comment: @strawdog к сожалению сюда нельзя прикреплять скрины и весь результат .info() не помещается из-за ограничения символов. Я так напишу, типа данных это колонки: 
year_of_release  4781 non-null   int64  

а вообще, в исходном датафрейме, я менял её на datetime

Comment: а вы отвыкайте постить сюда скриншоты. потому что это нарушает правила сайта. код должен быть в вопросе в воспроизводимом виде. попробуйте сделать не `act_platforms.query('year_of_release == "2015" and year_of_release == "2016"')`, а `act_platforms.query('year_of_release == 2015 and year_of_release == 2016')`

Comment: @strawdog всё равно только пустой датафрейм формируется :( Насчёт скринов - буду иметь в виду, спасибо!